# to_char() output as a json key isn't text? (Postgres)

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a json containing day names as keys and I'm trying to select the value from the json using today as a key, where today is Thursday. However this does not work as intended.

```
SELECT hoursJson->'normalHours'->'Thursday' FROM BusinessHours;
```

returns the hours contained in the json correctly, but

```
SELECT hoursJson->'normalHours'->to_char(current_date, 'Day') FROM BusinessHours;
```

returns nothing.

Why is `to_char(current_date, 'Day')` not equal to `'Thursday'`
when used as a json key? `to_char()` returns text so I don't know why these two keys aren't equal. How do I make them equal so I can use `to_char()` as a json key?

Thanks!

Comment: It is working on 9.4. Can you send some examples? You can check a parenthesis: SELECT jsonval->'xxx'->(func())'

Comment: I'm on 9.3, unfortunately.

Comment: @PavelStehule No it isn't working in 9.4, `to_char` blank-pads the return value when you use `'Day'` so `...->to_char(current_date, 'Day')` will only work properly on Wednesday (in an English locale too of course).

Comment: @muistooshort I was partially wrong - I tested a usage of function there, not tested to_char( 'Day')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a whitespace problem. From the [fine `to_char` manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE):

> `Day` full capitalized day name (blank-padded to 9 chars)

Note the "blank-padded" part. You're not getting `'Thursday'` from `to_char`, you're getting `'Thursday '` and those are different keys in JSON.

If you want to keep using `to_char` then you're going to have to deal with the trailing whitespace using something like:

```
...->trim(trailing ' ' from to_char(current_date, 'Day'))
...->regexp_replace(to_char(current_date, 'Day'), '\s+', '')
```

A quick demo of what's going on (which will work on Thursday or Friday):

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2a77b/23

You might want to use different keys in your JSON so that you won't have to deal with the whitespace at all or you could write your own function to hide away the `to_char` and `trim` nastiness.

Comment: It worked thanks! I'm using the trim method. Which one is more efficient?

Comment: @Teboto Probably `trim` but the difference is mostly likely too small to make any difference. Switching to day numbers in the JSON would be even better and would be locale-independent.